# ip and mac address linux

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to get the ip-address and mac-address as output in linux terminal.

I don't want 'addr' before the ip-address.
The mac-address needs to be in this form: `000C29DDED7C` (without ':' and all in capitals)

I tried this:

```
echo "ip-address: `/sbin/ifconfig | head -2 | grep 'inet ' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3` mac-address: `/sbin/ifconfig | head -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | tr ':' ' ' | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'`"
```

Gives me:

```
ip-address: addr:192.168.8.141 mac-address: 00 0C 29 AC 3C 02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add sed at two places which will remove "addr:"  and spaces between MAC address.

Below is the entire command

```
echo "ip-address: `/sbin/ifconfig | head -2 | grep 'inet ' | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/addr://g' |cut -d' ' -f3` mac-address: `/sbin/ifconfig | head -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | tr ':' ' ' |tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'|sed 's/ //g'`"
```

Output of this command is

```
ip-address: 10.137.108.181 mac-address: AC162D72A875
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the ips address with `egrep` :

```
ifconfig|egrep -o "([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+"
```

Getting the ips address without subnet mask, without "addr:" :

```
ifconfig|egrep -o "addr:([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+"|sed "s/addr://g"
```

Getting the mac address :

```
ifconfig|egrep -o "HWaddr [A-Za-z0-9:]+"|sed "s/HWaddr\ //"
```

You could catch the output of each command into a variable to print as you want :

```
interfaceNum=1
ip=$(/sbin/ifconfig|egrep -o "addr:([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+"|sed -n "s/addr://g;${interfaceNum}p")
mac=$(/sbin/ifconfig|egrep -o "HWaddr [A-Za-z0-9:]+"|sed -n "s/HWaddr\ //g;${interfaceNum}p")
echo "ip=$ip, mac=$mac"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use sed : echo "ip-address: `/sbin/ifconfig | head -2 | grep 'inet ' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3` mac-address: `/sbin/ifconfig | head -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 | tr ':' ' ' | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'`" | sed -e 's/addr://g'

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` can make it:

```
$ ifconfig | tr -s ' ' | awk -F" |addr:" 'NR==1 {gsub(":", "", $5);mac=toupper($5)} NR==2 {ip=$4} END{print "ip-address ==> " ip " mac ==> " mac}'
ip-address ==> 192.168.8.141 mac ==> 000C29AC3C02
```

- `tr -s ' '` squeezes multiple spaces, as you were already doing.
- `awk -F" |addr:"` sets field delimiter as "addr:" or space.
- `NR==1 {gsub(":", "", $5);mac=toupper($5)}` on line 1, get `mac` as 5th value based on above delimiter. Previously, the colons are deleted.
- `NR==2 {ip=$4}` on line 2, get `ip` as 4th value based on above delimiter.
- `END{print "ip-address ==> " ip " mac ==> " toupper(mac)}'` print result, with mac on upper case.